# Is there an API for creating google cloud platform credentials?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Google app engine projects can create new client ids. Is there an api to do this? The photo below is a screen shot of the button I click on to create a new client id.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is not an API for creating new client IDs.